# Virtual Machine Manager and pi4B 8 GB and redhat installed

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, firefox, virt-manager

I have Virtual Machine Manager installed on the Raspberry pi 4B 8 Gb with Bullseye.
I also installed RedHat but I don't have Gnome.
I am wondering if it is possible to run a GUI on Virtual Machine Manager with the pi 4B 8 GB.
If I want to start firefox I receive this error:
Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I run GUIs on low-powered HP Thinclients (t620 and t530) with 4GB memory. GUIs also work on VMs. Your error message has nothing to do with your Raspi's performance. How do you start firefox? Also clarify which OS the Raspi runs, and which OS is installed on the VM, and the size of the VM's RAM.

Comment: I now have Fedora workstation live and I had it running for a while but it got stuck. Now I don't remember what I did for settings in Virtual Machine Manager. I have Virtual Machine Manager on the raspberry pi 4B 8 GB with the Bullseye OS.